# messageReceived (netty) not called

Tags: java, netty, protocol-buffers

my source 
TestMessage - is my protobuf object

```
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            ChannelPipeline next = Channels.pipeline();

        next.addLast("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
            next.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(TestMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
        next.addLast("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
        next.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());


            return next;
        }

@Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        if (ch.isOpen()) {

            TestMessage req = (TestMessage) e.getMessage();
            System.out.println(req.getMessage());
            ch.close();

        }
    }
```

send

```
Socket fromserver = new Socket("localhost", 7283);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(), true);

        TestMessage.Builder message = TestMessage.newBuilder();

        message.setMessage("message .....");

        message.build();

        out.println(message);

        out.close();
        fromserver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a question. Where is messageReceived()?

ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder, ProtobufDecoder, ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender, ProtobufEncoder

four classes are in netty. But messageReceived() method must locate in CustomHandler class. And the class

have to add next instance of ChannelPipeline.

ex) if i make a ProtobufHandler class(extends SimpleChannelHandler) for messageReceived(),

```
ChannelPipeline next = Channels.pipeline();
next.addLast("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
next.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(TestMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
next.addLast("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
next.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());

next.addLast("protobufHandler", new ProtobufHandler()); //add this.
```

sorry, I have limited English proficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Netty 5.0.0 and testing some chat examples from GitHub which were developed for using older Netty versions. Those examples used the below code in client side to send string:

`channel.write(msg + "\r\n");`

The function messageReceived has been never called with my current Netty library. However, it has started being called after I changed the client code to flush string as the following:

`channel.writeAndFlush(msg + "\r\n");`